# Unity Gradle Build Failure

Tags: c#, android, android-studio, unity-game-engine, gradle

- How to fix unity 2020.1f gradle build failure. I need help with this. Please

```
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)



UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

* What went wrong:

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

A problem occurred configuring project ':launcher'.

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':launcher:classpath'.

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

   > Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:6.9.

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

     Searched in the following locations:

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/6.9/gradle-6.9.pom

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/6.9/gradle-6.9.pom

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

     Required by:

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

         project :launcher

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)



UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

* Try:

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)



UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)



UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

BUILD FAILED in 34s

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\bin\java.exe -classpath "C:\Users\Public\Documents\gradle-6.9-all\gradle-6.9\lib\gradle-launcher-6.9.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "bundleRelease"

stderr[

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':launcher'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':launcher:classpath'.
   > Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:6.9.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/6.9/gradle-6.9.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/6.9/gradle-6.9.pom
     Required by:
         project :launcher

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 34s
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
]
stdout[

]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <59b231ad19bf42f6b72bf2546a9b9393>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <59b231ad19bf42f6b72bf2546a9b9393>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <59b231ad19bf42f6b72bf2546a9b9393>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools.RunJava (System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.Action`1[T] progress, System.String error) (at <59b231ad19bf42f6b72bf2546a9b9393>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <59b231ad19bf42f6b72bf2546a9b9393>:0)
Rethrow as GradleInvokationException: Gradle build failed
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <59b231ad19bf42f6b72bf2546a9b9393>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <59b231ad19bf42f6b72bf2546a9b9393>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <59b231ad19bf42f6b72bf2546a9b9393>:0)
Rethrow as BuildFailedException: Exception of type 'UnityEditor.Build.BuildFailedException' was thrown.
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.CancelPostProcess.AbortBuild (System.String title, System.String message, System.Exception ex) (at <59b231ad19bf42f6b72bf2546a9b9393>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <59b231ad19bf42f6b72bf2546a9b9393>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess (UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea, System.String playerPackage, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <59b231ad19bf42f6b72bf2546a9b9393>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at <59b231ad19bf42f6b72bf2546a9b9393>:0)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <d1bec46880064709a5e713ad543e6d96>:0)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

Build completed with a result of 'Failed'
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 22 errors
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x0027c] in <d1bec46880064709a5e713ad543e6d96>:0 
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00080] in <d1bec46880064709a5e713ad543e6d96>:0 
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)
```

**I have been trying to build an apk bundle in unity 2020.1f with a targeted API 31 but I am getting this error. I download the SDK from android studio.
I am using gradle 6.9 to build the apk bundle.
 Can anyone help me, please I am freaking out!**

Answer (score 0):

oh, I fixed it by downloading the latest version of unity 2020 and I followed this video https://youtu.be/Jldd2CE37Xo. So Inorder to fix it just download the latest version of unity.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).